# Does Qui-Gon use his hands to eat after he catches Jar-Jar's tongue?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace

From [The Phantom Menace Script](https://web.archive.org/web/20120111195754/http://www.blueharvest.net/scoops/pm-script.shtml)

> ANAKIN smiles. JAR JAR attempts to snare another bit of food from the bowl
>   with his tongue, but QUI-GON, in a flash, grabs it between his thumb and
>   forefinger. JAR JAR is startled.
>
> QUI-GON : (Cont'd) Don't do that again.
>
> JAR JAR tries to acknowledge with some silly mumbling. QUI-GON lets go of
>   the tongue, and it snaps back into JAR JAR's mouth.

[image: QUI-GON catches Jar-Jar's tongue]

and later :

> SHMI : Anakin, don't...
>
> JAR JAR belches. **There is silence for a moment as they eat.**

I'm trying to find a video extract of this meal, but I cannot.
Does he use his hands to eat after he catches Jar-Jar's tongue, or at least, doe he wash it or wipe it off?

Comment: Maybe midichlorians are antibacterial. ;)

Comment: He should have used a Force tongue-grab instead.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The grab occurs at 41:33. After this point, the conversation with Anakin begins and Qui Gon is *not* seen eating anything. He drinks from a cup (with his right hand, which did not touch Jar Jar) at 42:08, but does not touch solid food again. It's worth noting that when he does eat earlier in the same scene (41:27) he is also using his right hand.

I would be more concerned about the rest of the fruit in that bowl. The original tongue-grab does not look like a precision maneuver.

Comment: "The original tongue-grab does not look like a precision maneuver." hehe made me chuckle +1